# How to empty a set and list in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you empty a set?
e.g

```
l1 = set([1, 2, 3])
```

What if I have a list? How do I empty the list?

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: But `([1, 2, 3])` is not a set.

Comment: You can also do `l1[:] = []` to clear a list.

Comment: @Mark Because in that code you happily left out you probably wrote this `set([1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: @Mark,  `([1,2,3])` creates a list so if it creates a set on codeskulptor then there is something very weird going on.

Comment: @Mark You __never have a set there__. What makes you think you do?

Comment: @Mark It is probably best if you post the exact sample code that generates the error. Then it will become clear where the set comes from :)

Comment: @Mark, I just tested on codeskulpter and it does not create a set, it creates a list http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_IN3pePJdTm_2.py, Your image output also shows l2 which is the reference to l1 and that is an empty list so you also get a list.

Comment: There are no sets in any of your examples.  You can wrap as many layers of parentheses around a list as you like and it will still be a list.  If you want a `set`, use `set(x)` for some list `x`.  For example, `set([1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: So the question is this:  You've been using lists all along without realizing.  Is that what you want?  Or do you want to learn about sets and rewrite your code to use them instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `clear()` method:

```
l1.clear()
```

Comment: Note this only works in Python 3, not Python 2 (assuming `l1` is a list).

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're trying to do is to empty a l1 for that you can use a lost of methods, here is one

1) " del " method:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]

del l1[:]

print(l1)
```

you get:

```
[]
```

you can use as argument `[:]`, or `[0:]` or `[0:3]` for list `l1`